# How can I display decimals as a percentage while keeping the formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA code for an Excel file that contains formulas to format the design.

I have at rows C10-->J10 a percentage row and the displayed result is a decimal such as `0.32` and I would like to make it show as `32 %` while keeping the cell formula that way if I change any value the percentage updates.

So far I have multiplied the cells by `100` and added the `%` symbol and the values look as I want but the formulas are gone.

Here's what I did:

```
    For Each Cell In Range("C10:U10")
        Cell.Value = Cell.Value * 100
    Next Cell
    Range("C10:J10").NumberFormat = "##0.00 \%"
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't re-calculate `Cell.Value = Cell.Value * 100` just set your number format to

```
Range("C10:J10").NumberFormat = "0.00 %"   ' will show 0.32 as 32,00 %
```

or

```
Range("C10:J10").NumberFormat = "0 %"   ' will show 0.32 as 32 %
```

The value in the cell will still be `0.32` but it is shown as `32,00 %` or `32 %` and the formula will stay intact.

Comment: As he is provide little information, therefore I am trying to solve his problem for formula is gone...He format is working fine in excel by display decimal value, i don't there is any issue.

Comment: @KinSiang With your formula his formula was gone as well because you replaced his formula by another one. That wasn't solving the issue.

Comment: Yes, i know the issue, that is why I want to know what is he really trying to do with the formula..

Comment: @KinSiang Doesn't matter what the formula actually does. This information is not needed, because he said the result of the formula is `0.32` and he wants it displayed as `32 %` but not changing the formula. And that can be perfecty done with the number format in my answer. So all information we need is already in the question.

Comment: It is fine, as long as he get what he want will do.